# Phone development: interact with the call?

Tags: iphone, android, windows-phone-7, phone-call

Today, the focus of a cell phone's capabilities is drifting away from plain making a phone call.

And somehow, this shows in the API's too.  Therefor I'm wondering: if I want to write an app that e.g. pitches up, records, scrambles... an incoming call - you know, the voice on the other side -, what aspect of the API should I use?

I looked into Android, into Windows Phone, iPhone... (briefly), but had no luck.  Is this just unintended usage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is also not possible with Windows Phone 7. There were, however, API methods for interacting with incoming and outgoing calls and texts in Windows Mobile.

The reason this is not possible in Windows Phone 7 comes down to a deliberate decision around data security and the aim that apps on the phone shouldn't be able to do something without the user specifically knowing about it. This prevents, amongst other things, malicious apps having information about or access to potentially sensitive data.

Comment: Thanks Matt; have you got any reference on that deliberate decision?

Comment: @xtofl can't find it written anywhere (aftger a quick search) but have heard it from many talks/videos from MSFT staff.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible in Android, except *maybe* via firmware modifications.

Comment: Specifically, modifications of the firmware for the radio processor, wheras most custom firmware work is confined to the applications processor that runs linux/android/apps.

Answer (score 1):

There’s no way to do that with the iPhone SDK. It *may* be possible through jailbreaking, but I’m not familiar enough with it to speak on it.

Answer (score 1):

Given the limited accessibility of in-call audio but ready access to microphone/speaker and data on current smartphones, would probably be easiest to do this as part of a VOIP calling application.